# RunTime Error on online compilers when using string in c++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++14

I am trying to run this code on online compilers and it shows Runtime errors while it runs perfectly locally. The parts of code that are not being used have been commented out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;

        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        string ans;
        int noOfApple=0,noOfBanana=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='a')
            {
                noOfApple++;
            }
            else
            {
                noOfBanana++;
            }
        }
        int noOfABlock=ceil(noOfApple/x);
        //int noOfBBlock=ceil(noOfBanana/y);
        int length=floor(noOfBanana/(noOfABlock-1));
        int remainderB=noOfBanana%(noOfABlock-1);
        int counter=0;
        //condition for '*'

        if(noOfBanana<(noOfABlock-1))
        {
            int q=noOfBanana;
            for(int i=0;i<(noOfABlock-1);i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
                {
                    ans[counter++]='a';
                }
                if(q>0)
                {
                    ans[counter++]='b';
                    q--;
                }
                else
                {
                    ans[counter++]='*';
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            ans[counter++]='a';
        }

        }
        else{
        for(int i =0;i<(noOfABlock-1);i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<x;j++)
            {
                ans[counter++]='a';
            }
            for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
            {
                ans[counter++]='b';
            }
            while(remainderB>0)
            {
                remainderB--;
                ans[counter++]='b';
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            ans[counter++]='a';
        }
        }


        cout<<ans<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input for this program:-

```
6
ab
1 1
aab
1 1
aabb
1 2
aaaaab
2 1
aaaa
1 3
aaaaa
2 2
```

When Arrays are used we  have to initialize the size of the arrays as they are static but as string are dynamic we do not need to initialize with a size.

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: Think about what happens if `noOfABlock` or `noOfBBlock` is `1`.

Comment: Don’t use `0` instead of `false`, it makes your code confusing. Similarly, don’t use `0` (or its macro, `NULL`) instead of `nullptr` since you’re on C++14.

Comment: `noOfBBlock` isn't used, so `y` isn't really used either. Just remove them from the the program if you don't use them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Updated the code but this won't cause Runtime Error.

Comment: @divyamsingh1313 No, but it's not a minimal example if you keep dead code in it. It makes it harder to read for everyone and can make people wonder if you made a mistake with regards to that code. Can you edit your question an include the exact input you give to the program as NathanOliver asked for?

Comment: When I run it with your input example, I get a division by zero exception at the expression `noOfBanana / (noOfABlock - 1)`. I also got three compiler warnings, which were easily fixed, and probably not causing a run-time error. You should provide all the information you have about the run-time error you got.